# How to close android browser after redirecting to my app?

Tags: android

How can i close the browser once i got redirected to my app. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: There's no need to close the browser or worry about other applications running; Android handles this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not start Browser. You can start your own activity with WebView on it. So when you're being redirected you can handle this event and close the activity.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no possibility to take influence on other activities, like closing etc.

Answer (score 0):

Work around for problem
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html