# android how to close browser after url scheme

Tags: android, url-scheme

In App1, I clicked on a url which will redirects to myapp://
This caused the browser to open before myapp activity will start. The problem is that myapp activity shows a chathead kind of display, hence the background should be App1. But the backgound has become the browser.

How can I close the browser so the background is App1?

Comment: Seems like the way to do it is to use a WebView instead and not open a Browser. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341489 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353973

Comment: u can close the browser from pid also

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't close any third party app.
Your problem seems to be that a web browser is opening first instead of your app.
This may be due to the scheme you're using.

In order to be launched without opening a web browser, your app should register a custom scheme such as: `yoursheme://someValue` instead of a url scheme `http://someValue`.